# jQuery ajax done function not firing with jQuery file upload

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm working with jQuery file upload which upload 1 file and formdata.
The file and data are uploading successfully in back end but I'm not getting the response back inside done function. The backend is Java, spring controller which return object of a ModelAndView. In browser i am getting status 200 OK but why the done function of my ajax request not firing?
 Expect help from all of you..

Following is my code:

```
$("#uploadMail").fileupload({
    maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
    add: function(e, data) {
        cleanErrors();
        var result = data.files;
        result.forEach(function(file) {

            console.log(file.name);
            $("#fileName").val(file.name);
        });
        $(".saveFile").off('click');
        $(".saveFile").on('click', function(event) {
            cleanErrors();
            event.preventDefault();
            var mailCategory = $("#mailCategory").val();
            data.submit(function(event) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: contextPath + '/mail/upload.sf?mailCategory' + mailCategory,
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "text",
                    data: data

                }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    alert("hii" + textStatus);
                    alert(data);
                }).fail(function() {
                    alert("done2");
                })

            });



        });
        hideWait();
    }

});
```

Beginner in jQuery and javascript apologizes for the mistake done if any. Thank you in advance.

Comment: is the .savefile dynamically created?

Comment: @amit_183 It is just a button class not given in styles. <input type="button" value="Save" class="button_01 saveFile"> ,I changed it to id, then also not getting response but form is submitting.

Answer (score 0):

I think the plugin you are using depends on flash. This upload feature demands flash plugin to be installed in browser for upload feature. I strogly recommend using Formdata with jquery.

see the example below

**Preparations**

You can give your whole form to FormData() for processing

```
var form = $('form')[0]; // You need to use standard javascript object here
var formData = new FormData(form);
```

or specify exact data for FormData()

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('section', 'general');
formData.append('action', 'previewImg');
// Attach file
formData.append('image', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
```

Sending form

Ajax request with jquery will looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Your url here',
    data: formData,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false, // NEEDED, DON'T OMIT THIS (requires jQuery 1.6+)
    processData: false, // NEEDED, DON'T OMIT THIS
    // ... Other options like success and etc
});
```

After this it will send ajax request like you submit regular form with enctype="multipart/form-data"

Update: This request cannot work without type:"POST" in options, cause all files must be sent via POST request.

Hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: Yes, by formdata i tried and its working fine. But my question is why it is not working with jquery file upload .how can i fix this? i am using jquery.fileupload.js. File is uploading succesfully ,and done function for  $("#uploadMail").fileupload also working. but ajax request's done or success not triggering.

Comment: Which JQuery version do you use?

Comment: Ok can you try ajax success and error callbacks instead of done and fail?. Also \please specify the version of jquery you are using

Comment: @Bimal Kumar Tried.No changes.

Comment: I'm using jquery-1.11.2.min.js

Comment: have you tried ajax success and error callbacks instead of done and fail